# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 с mssql server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Здравствуйте. Раньше пользовался visual studio 2013. Установил 2015 community. Создал консольное приложение, с помощью code first создал базу данных. Пытаюсь посмотреть содержимое, а в контекстном меню нет такого пункта почему то. Когда 2 раза кликаю по таблице, структура не открывается, почему так подскажите пожалуйста. Прикладываю скрин, если ещё какая то информация нужна будет, выложу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75928/discussion-on-question-by--microsoft-visual-studio-2015--mssql-server-201).